# In between not working in Oracle

Tags: oracle

Hello I am trying to fetch date using in between function in oracle but it's not working I have below mentioned data in Oracle table

[image]

I am using below mentioned query to filter dates and it's give me error both are menioned in image

[image]

Plz help me out this

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems that you are trying to convert `date` value to `date` with `to_date(...)` function. The type of column `receivedtime` looks `date`, so try not to use `to_date` function for that column, like the following:

```
select * 
from use_news
where clientid=159
  and receivedtime between to_date('04/05/2012', 'mm/dd/yyyy')
                       and to_date('11/14/2014', 'mm/dd/yyyy')
;
```

Comment: Just had a long-ish rant about this - in a nutshell, I recommend avoiding BETWEEN for dates.  In example here, you'll include records received at 11/14/2014 12:00:00 a.m. but not 11/14/2014 1:00:00 a.m. (worse, the same records will be included on "BETWEEN 11/14/2014 AND <FUTURE-DATE>" - used plainly like this, BETWEEN will give you overlapping ranges).  Fixing this for BETWEEN requires functions on receivedtime (losing index/stats) or funky Oracle date math (dt - 1/24/60/60).  Recommend using two conditions: "RECEIVEDTIME >= TO_DATE(...) AND RECEIVEDTIME < TO_DATE(...)".  Removes all issues.